# sa-compile update error with rule compilation

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, spamassassin, dpkg

I have an install of Ubuntu 18.04.5 and I'm trying to update the sa-compile (version 3.4.2) package because I have a file server set up on it which uses spamassassin (version 3.4.2). Every time I try to proceed with the update, though, it gives the error `command 're2c -i -b -o scanner1.c scanner1.re' failed: exit 0` and dpkg gives the error `installed sa-compile package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 12`.

After some searching, I thought it was a problem with the "debian-spamd" account's shell. However, the shell wasn't the problem (changing it from `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` didn't solve the issue). Permissions don't seem to be the issue, either: the `/var/lib/spamassassin/compiled` directory is owned by "debian-spamd".

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After editing the `/var/lib/dpkg/sa-compile.postinst` file and removing the `--quiet` part from the command for `sa-compile`, I found that the command couldn't allocate enough memory. I rebooted the server, and ran the command again. This time, it compiled and exited properly.